# Nneed to calculate average of NON sequential multiple cells & I want to exclude values = 0 or Empty Cell with AVERAGEIF

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2011

Nneed to calculate average of NON sequential multiple cells and I want to exclude values = 0 or Empty Cell with AVERAGEIFS.

There is a mistake in my formula but I can't find a way to have it since value are NOT in sequencial order:

```
=AVERAGEIFS($C$9,$C$19,$C$29,$C$39,$C$49,$C$59,$C$69,$C$79,$C$89,$C$99,$C$109,$C$119,$C$129,$C$139,$C$149,$C$159,$C$169,$C$179,$C$190,$C$200,$C$210,$C$220,$C$231,$C$241,$C$251,$C$261,$C$271,$C$281,$C$291,$C$301,$C$311,$C$321,$C$331,$C$341,$C$351,$C$361,$C$371,$C$381,$C$391,$C$401,$C$411,$C$421,$C$431,$C$441,$C$451,$C$461,$C$471,$C$481,$C$491,$C$501,$C$512,$C$522,$C$532,$C$542,$C$552,$C$562;"<>0")
```

Any help ?

Regards !

Answer (score 1):

AVERAGEIF/AVERAGEIFS cannot be used with non-contiguous ranges.

Instead, you can calculate average by taking the SUM and count of non-zero cells.  You may have to adjust the -0.01 if you have small negatives:

```
=SUM(theRange)/(SUM(INDEX(FREQUENCY((theRange),0),2),INDEX(FREQUENCY((theRange),-0.01),1)))
```

If you won't have any negative numbers, you can use the simpler:

```
=SUM(theRange)/INDEX(FREQUENCY((theRange),0),2)
```

Comment: @mcalex

I found something here using Averageif for non-continuous ranges ---> http://tinyurl.com/lm2jpub  but I'm not able to apply it  ??? could you help me cause I'm not very good with excel ? Thx

Answer (score 0):

The mistake in the formula is that it only takes one argument for the range.  You have multiple arguments.  A couple of ways to overcome this.

From the remarks for the [AVERAGEIFS](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/averageifs-function-HA010047493.aspx) function:  *Each cell in average_range is used in the average calculation only if all of the corresponding criteria specified are true for that cell.*

I don't know the AVERAGEIFS() function but that remark suggests you can add a crieria that queries if there is a value in the cell and doesn't include it in the calculation if it doesn't.

If this doesn't work, a workaround is to copy the values that you do want included into a contiguous array so you can call the function properly.

Comment: I found something here using Averageif for non-continuous ranges ---> http://tinyurl.com/lm2jpub  but I'm not able to apply it  ??? could you help me cause I'm not very good with excel ? Thx